# Match string in list and use other attribute of the matched object with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.forms

I'm having a list with Gasstations:

```
public class GasStation
    {
        [JsonProperty("costcentre")]
        public string CostCentre { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

private IEnumerable<GasStation> gasStationList;
public IEnumerable<GasStation> GasStationList
{
    get => gasStationList;
    set => SetValue(ref gasStationList, value);
}
```

I'm having a string which I am comparing with the `CostCentre` attribute of a `GasStation` Object:

`GasStationList.Any(x => x.CostCentre == string);`

When this matches `true` I want to use this matched GasStation and show its `Name` in my XAML Binding.

Is there a way?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linq namespace offeres a method `FirstOrDefault<TSource>`, which returns the first item which matches a given criteria or `default<TSource>`, if there is no matching item in the enumeration.

```
GasStation station = gasStationList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CostCentre == string);
```